# Does SOLR support substring function for fields of type String?

Tags: solr, substring

In my query I need to return a substring (matching a specific regex) of a field instead of the entire field. Looking at the list of supported functions (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#Available_Functions) seems that there's no such function out of the box! Does anybody know what the recommended solution is?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [copyField](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields) whose fieldType has a [PatternCaptureGroupFilter](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PatternCaptureGroupFilterFactory). Your copyField should have only the regex matched portion.

Eg: your original field is like

```
url: http://www.example.com
```

but you don't want the `http://` portion to show in the retrieved field.

Define a new fieldType in your schema like this:

```
<fieldType name="url_base" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
 <analyzer>
   <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.PatternCaptureGroupFilterFactory" 
           pattern="https?://([a-zA-Z\-_0-9.]+)" 
           preserve_original="false"/>
 </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

so the capture group within the parentheses gets only `www.example.com`.

Then define your copy field like this:

```
<field name="baseUrl" type="url_base" indexed="false" stored="true" />
<copyField source="url" dest="baseUrl" />
```

Your query can then be like `/search?q=url:example&fl=baseUrl`.

Of course, this is assuming `url` is a text field. If it is a string field, then do either exact matching or regex matching on it.

Comment: This is an indexing time solution, which requires re-indexing of the exiting documents, right? I'm more interested in query time solutions.

Comment: Yes, this is an index time solution. I am not aware of a query time solution for this. The alternative is to write your own client code which consumes Solr's response and produces the regex capture group.